# I have a string as '11-2020', I want to convert it as 'NOV-2020' in Python

Tags: python, datetime

What is the best pythonic way to covert, a string as '11-2020' to 'NOV-2020' in Python.

I tried below code :

```
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%Y').strftime('%b-%Y'))
```

But getting output like : Nov-2020 (I want Nov to be in caps)

Comment: use `datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%Y').strftime('%b-%Y').upper()`

Answer (score 1):

```
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%Y').strftime('%b-%Y').upper())
#NOV-2020
```